# Making a BoxDecoration blurred

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been working on this for a few hours now, and unfortunately it's impossible to make this BoxDecoration blurred! Does anyone know how to do it? Unfortunately ChatGPT wasn't able to help me.

```
class CustomNavItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;
  final bool isSelected;

  const CustomNavItem(
      {required this.icon, required this.label, required this.isSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Icon(icon),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: isSelected
                ? Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 3))
                : null,
          ),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey[600],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried several versions of this code, but it justs blurs all my app, like with this code:

```
[...]
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Icon(icon),
        Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey[600],
          ),
        ),
        isSelected
            ? BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                child: Container(
                  height: 3,
                  width: 50, // Tu peux ajuster la largeur selon tes besoins
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withAlpha(0), // Semi-transparent
                ),
              )
            : Container(
                height: 3,
                width: 50, // La même largeur que le Container ci-dessus
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do what you want?

```
ClipRect(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0),
            child: 

               YOUR_OBJECT_HERE_THAT_IS_NOT_BLURRED

   ), 
),
```